# getting an error while executing the code

Tags: python, python-2.6

In the below code i want to print the lines which are between "first", and on those line searching for "new.txt" line.. when i am running i get an error :

```
if "first" in lines[i+n]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

my code:

```
def find_path(self):
        f = open("/output",'w')
        for line in self.logs:
            f.write(line)
        f = open('/output','rb')
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i,line in enumerate(lines):    
            if "first" in line:
                pattern = line
                for n in range(1,len(lines)):
                    if "first" in lines[i+n]:
                        break
                    else: 
                        if "new.txt" in line:
                            print line
                        print lines[i+n]
        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `i+n` can be and will be greater than length of `lines` list.

```
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
```

That enumeration creates values for `i` from `0` to `len(lines) - 1`, so the maximum value of `i` is `len(lines) - 1`.

The following lines tell us that values of `n` can be from `1` to `len(lines) - 1`, so maximum value of `n` is `len(lines) - 1` again:

```
for n in range(1,len(lines)):
    if "first" in lines[i+n]:
        break
```

So, value of `i + n` can be from `1` to `2 * (len(lines) - 1)` - that's why you're getting `IndexError`.

Comment: How to resolve it?.. i tried to use len(lines)-1 but still getting error

Comment: I don't catch the idea of your code, if you'll explain it, maybe I'll find the way to help you fix the issue.